# .htaccess rewrite parent folder to sub folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

how can i redirect from server.ip/~bogo/api/*  to server.ip/~bogo/api/public/*?
any help please

Here's htacces in api directory

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
     RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
      RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

my htacces in public directory

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

but i got 404 error??

Comment: I assume you get an internal server error. Is this correct? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: yes i get internal server error and my htaccess file in api directory

Comment: And what does your server's error log say specifically about this error?

Comment: sorry i get 404 error not internal server error

Comment: If you add in `public` yourself, do you get the page you expect? Does the other .htaccess work?

Comment: when i tried http://server-ip/~bogo/api/public/ it's work but when i tried  http://server-ip/~bogo/api/public/merchants not worked

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite is actually enabled? `index.php` is commenly checked and displayed by Apache if you request a directory. `_url` would be empty/null instead of containing a slash, but I doubt it makes much of a difference.

Comment: yes mod_rewrite enabled

Comment: Is `Options FollowSymLinks` enabled? Do you have any more `.htaccess` files, for example in the www-root? Does adding `RewriteRule foo /bar [R,L]` to one of your `.htaccess` files and going to that directory followed by `/foo` redirect you to `/bar`?

Comment: Options FollowSymLinks was not enable but after i enable it still no change when i tried RewriteRule foo /bar [R,L] in htaccess of api directory yes it's redirect me to /bar

Comment: @Sumurai8  when i tried RewriteRule  ^$ public/ [R,L] and tried this url http://server.ip/~bogo/api it's redirect me to http://server.ip /home/bogo/public_html/api/public/ and get 404 error

Comment: That /home/bogo suggests that `RewriteBase` might fix the problem instead of the full-url-approach that you have used. I think removing "`http://server.ip`" from your solution should still work, as that is automatically removed if you are on that server in the first place. I can't test it though.

Comment: correct i removed server.ip and it's still working

Answer (score 1):

Ok i solved it here's my solution

api directory htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~bogo/api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/
RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1
</IfModule>
```

public directory htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~bogo/api/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache will go through `.htaccess` until no rules match anymore. The problem you are most likely facing, is that the new url is being matched by the regex of the same rule. You have created an infinite loop. You can fix this by making sure the rule doesn't match if the url already has 'public' in it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/
  RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: could you translate this ````(.*) public/$1 [L]````

Comment: This rule matches everything, and puts it in capture group 1. Then it prefixes it with public and adds the contents of capture group 1 after it (`$1`). `(.*)` should match everything, because it is greedy, but I would write it as `^(.*)$` if I were to write it now.